# Подключение к веб-сервисам из Android на java

Tags: java, android, soap, веб-служба, wsdl

Привет. Разрабатываю приложение под Android на Java в Android Studio, которое должно взаимодействовать с веб-сервисом WSDL, предоставляемым 1C, (пока его нет, буду тестировать с веб-сервисом на .NET WCF). Как вообще делается подключение/вызов сервиса на Java, какую библиотеку использовать? Нагуглил какую то ksoap2android, но документация оставляет желать лучшего, да и это сторонняя Open-source библиотека. А есть ли что нибудь более "правильное"?

Comment: посмотрите на http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: это вроде REST клиент, а мне нужен WSDL

Comment: добавьте эту информацию в вопрос

Comment: WSDL - это не тип web-сервиса, это язык дескриптора описывающего web-сервис. Если вам не нравится KSOAP, можете попробовать JSoap или IceSoap. Кроме того, Google подсказывает, что с SOAP можно работать и с помощью Retrofit.

Comment: как это не тип, в REST данные передаются в формате JSON, в SOAP - в формате xml. Понятно что это все внутри HTTP, и можно вообще вручную все делать, но использовать специализированную библиотеку удобнее. К тому же под Android работает далеко не все что есть в Java, к примеру в Spring есть то что мне нужно, но под Android оно не работает, есть spring for android, в нем даже есть REST, но нет SOAP, как то так